# What does $R_P$ mean, for a ring $R$ and an ideal $P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, notation

What does $R_P$ mean, for a ring $R$ and an ideal $P$? This appeared in some notes by a teacher of mine, but he didn't define this notation.

He used it as follows: suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $S$ a multiplicative system, and $P$ a prime ideal of $R$. Prove that $(RS^{-1})_{PS^{-1}}\simeq R_P$. I know what $R_P$ means, but I don't know what $(RS^{-1})_{PS^{-1}}$ means.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, definitely localization. $R_P$ is localization of $R$ reletive to the multiplication set $T=R\setminus P$, and this is only multiplicative if $P$ is prime.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring#Examples

Answer (score 4):

Given a commutative ring, $R$ and a multiplicative set $S$, the ring $RS^{-1}$ is called the localization of $R$ relative to $S$.

In particular, if $P$ is a prime ideal, then the set $T=R\setminus P$ is a multiplicative set, and the ring $RT^{-1}$ is written as $R_P$.

See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) page for ring localization. $R_P$ is mentioned in the examples.

Note, the Wikipedia page uses a different notation, $S^{-1}R$. But, given commutativity, that's not important.

Comment: Usually this is denoted $S^{-1}R$ or $R[S^{-1}]$.

Comment: It is also quite common to write $R_S$ to have the same meaning as $S^{-1}R$.  It would seem to conflict with the $R_P$ notation when $P$ is a prime ideal, but one always has $P^{-1}R = 0$, so there's minimal risk of confusion there..